# Good CSS Books/Resource

Tags: css, css-framework

I used to play around with CSS and 5 years later here I am. I don't have a clue of what CSS means now-a-days.

I was wondering if you guys knows what the best resources and books are to learn CSS. I would like books that cover the basics and a little advanced.

1 answer per post please.

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, why only one answer per post?

Comment: @ben, usually so that the community can vote up which one they belive is best. But that usually goes hand-in-hand with CW.

Comment: 'List of' questions should be community wiki. I've converted this one.

Answer (score 3):

[www.csszengarden.com](http://www.csszengarden.com)

Comment: Not a book but probably the best resource out there

Comment: The CSS Zen garden is a fun exercise in displaying the same markup in a variety of ways, but I don't think it's one of the best ways to learn CSS. It's a good resource to help you see what's possible.

Comment: The Zen garden is getting long in the tooth. It certainly deserves accolades for what it has accomplished, but I really don't see it as being the most useful resource anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This is a *great* thread from StackOverflow: [**What is the best book on CSS?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199486/what-is-the-best-book-on-css)

Also, I'm particularly fond of [**CSS Mastery: Advanced Web Standards Solutions**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430223979). It does a really nice job of explaining some of the peculiar things in CSS as though they make sense!

Comment: I find it very strange that people keep recommending the book by Eric Meyer. I own a copy of this book, and I have never once found it to be of any use to me whatsoever, plus it seems completely unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

I found the first edition of CSS The Missing Manual (O'Reilly) a good accessible introduction.

There is now a [second edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596802455/).

Answer (score 2):

[Bulletproof Web Design](http://astore.amazon.com/simplebits-20/detail/0321509021) is completely and utterly fantastic. The first CSS book I bought since getting back into web design and still the best I've read.

Comment: I totally agree with Bobby Jack. This is a good book.

Answer (score 1):

Keep these two links FOREVER in your bookmark bar, they will serve you well:

CSS Selectors and charts of browser support:
http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/

CSS Selectors and hacks to target specific browsers:
http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks#in_css-selectors

Answer (score 0):

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) has a nice tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

[Think Vitamin Video Tutorials](http://membership.thinkvitamin.com/?aid=17)

Has some great videos on CSS, all the way from beginner - look in the Fundamentals Videos.

Answer (score 0):

[quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/). Especially like the compatibility tables.